# Rename a file in a for-loop with python and linux

Tags: python, linux

I have the following "problem":

I have a file with a lot of inodes, each of which is on a single line.
Now I would like to go through these lines with Python and insert each individual line into a Linux command. To do this, I iterate the file with a for loop.
With the icat command I can extract a single inode to a destination with one command. However, I have to specify the target name of the file every time.
My problem now is that I enter the icat command with subprocess.run in the for loop and want to assign a variable name to the file for each run. Unfortunately, I don't know how.

File and file_dir are variables.

```
with open(file, "r") as f:
    for i in f.readlines():
        subprocess.run(["icat /dev/loop1/" + i + "> " + file_dir], shell=True)
    print("finish")
```

How can I use a variable or a Linux command to name the file to be extracted differently for each pass?

Comment: The question is about linux commands, not really about python

Answer (score 0):

Change file_dir with every for loop run.

```
with open(file, "r") as f:
    counter = 0
    for i in f.readlines():
        subprocess.run(["icat /dev/loop1/" + i + "> " + file_dir + "img" + counter], shell=True)
    counter += 1
    print("finish")
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer.
The file_dir is only a string with the path of the dir.
If i add a/the counter, than the path of file is for example /home/user/desktop/0.
The inodes are from images - so i must add a string. For example 01.img

Comment: @Steven84 If you feel my I amswered your question, you can  accept my answer.